# Setting Dynamic theme colors the sharepoint 2013 master Page

Tags: 2013, master-page, css, theme

I have been following [this](https://bniaulin.wordpress.com/2012/12/31/how-to-edit-the-sharepoint-2013-preview-file-for-a-master-page/) article, which talks about setting theme color to the master page via css.

What i am interested is in knowing the capability of SharePoint, whether it is possible using CSS to apply theme colors to say footer using the theme inbuild keywords like `.Footer{ (themeColor:"SuiteBarBackground") }.` in the custom CSS file.

So that when a new theme is selected the color of the footer automatically changes based on the themeColor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I haven't tried this myself I believe that answer is yes as long as you upload your custom css file to the Themable folder in the style library. From [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn266906.aspx): "Only CSS files that are stored in the Themable folder in the Style library are recognized by the theming engine."

Something to keep in mind, when you go to change your theme it will also reset your masterpage to seattle or oslo depending on the theme you choose. So after setting the theme just go back to Site Settings > Masterpage and set it back to your custom master.